# Using $interval with get request

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm attempting to create new get request using $interval. The result of the get request will update the model every second. But the interval is not being invoked :

https://plnkr.co/edit/SudMFW8vSCCflyN0eJGl?p=preview

The interval is defined within a directive , maybe this is an incorrect use of interval with directive ?

src below :

```
2. http-hello2.html

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl">

<label>Filter: <input ng-model="search"></label> 

  <status-viewer ng-repeat="sourceUrl in sourceUrls | filter:search track by $index " url="sourceUrl"></status-viewer>
</div>


  </body>
</html>

<!--<h1>{{url}}</h1>-->
<div>
    <p>{{model}}</p>
</div>

var myapp = angular.module('app', []).controller('FetchCtrl', FetchCtrl)

myapp.directive('statusViewer', function ($http , $interval) {
            return { 
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html', 
                scope: {
                    url: '='
                },  
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

                    console.log('invoked')

                    var refreshData = function() {
                    $http.get(scope.url).success(function (data) {
                        scope.model = JSON.stringify(data);
                    });
                 };

                    var promise = $interval(refreshData, 1000);

                    // Cancel interval on page changes
                    scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
                    if (angular.isDefined(promise)) {
                      $interval.cancel(promise);
                      promise = undefined;
                     }
                   });

                    $http.get(scope.url).success(function (data) {
                        scope.model = JSON.stringify(data);
                    });
                }
            };
        });

function FetchCtrl($scope, $http, $q , $parse) {


$scope.sourceUrls = [
                'http-hello2.html'
            ,'http-hello2.html'];



}
```

Update.

Is using interval & directive to update model in this way correct ?

Comment: If you add some logging you'll notice the `refreshData` function is getting called every second

Comment: @paultrone thanks, yes I can see it's being invoked.

Comment: So since you see it is being invoked....does that close this question or is there another issue? Not clear what problem is

Comment: ok, is the problem that it's not grabbing the template contents?

Comment: @paultrone please see question update

Comment: why are you using `stringify` on response data?

Comment: @charlietfl I shouldn't be using stringify, plunkr updated : https://plnkr.co/edit/YlAVlf6apGHWQc1GfE6y?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

using `scope.$watch` is a more ideal way than `$interval` to fire off a function based on a scope variable's changes, since it will only execute code if there are actual changes to your variables.  Something like this would work:

```
scope.$watch('url', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    $http.get(...).success(function(data) {
      scope.model = data;
    });
  }
}
```